# EXCEL: Unique alphanumeric code with certain characters excluded (without VBA / duplicates)

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a list =5 alphanumeric characters.

They cannot contain `1`, and `i` and there cannot be duplicates when dragging / copying the code down.

The characters that are allowed are:

`023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ` (Capital)

I have tried numerous of options but I can't seem to figure this one out.

Cheers

Comment: duplicates?  Does that mean the same character cannot be used or the combination of 5 characters cannot duplicate?

Comment: What is the most promising of the options that you have tried? Are you expecting them to be random looking?

Comment: It can be used more the once. So for example
AX42P
AX42Z is ok

The most promising so far is:
In 
cel A1: 023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ
cdl B1: =MID($A$1;RANDBETWEEN(5;LEN($A$1));5)

But they do not always show 5 chars and have duplicates.

Comment: can the characters duplicate in the group of 5?

Comment: Yes I.E
E2345 -
E3456 is ok.

Comment: Create a named formula in the Name Manager --> `Pallette: ="023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ"` Then use this formula for the random codes: `=MID(Pallette,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(Pallette,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(Pallette,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(Pallette,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(Pallette,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1)` This will give you randomized codes, but there is no guarantee that they will be unique (but duplicates will be rare).

Comment: no I mean is A1111 valid?

Comment: Ah sorry, yes that should be valid yes (A2222) since 1 should be excluded).

Comment: I am trying it now, thanks for the responses :)

Comment: if one has office 365: `=CONCAT(MID("023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ",RANDARRAY(5,,1,34,TRUE),1))` but as stated above it would not guarantee a unique but there are  45,435,424 unique combinations and the chance of a dup is slim.

Comment: Is generating the list in order (vs random) OK? For example `00000`, `00002`, `00003`, etc.

Comment: By the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), the chance of a duplicate is not as small as you might expect. For example, if you have around 7000 such ID's the probability of a duplicate somewhere among those 7000 is around 50%. It depends on how many IDs you are trying to generate and how costly a collision is if you can ignore the probability of a duplicate with purely random choices.

Comment: xidgel yes that's ok. Excel hero I'm an kinda confused with the name manager. Correct me if I am wrong: In the name manager I refer it to: Pallette="...." paste code in other cell. I get #NAME?

Comment: @xidgel as stated there are `45,435,424` you would almost fill an entire sheet to get them all.

Comment: Sorry Scott unfortunately its Office 2016

Comment: @RJ34 on ExcelHero's formula you can put the string in A1 and replace `Pallette` in the formula with `$A$1`

Comment: In the Name Manager (Ctrl-F3) click on the New button. Pallette is what goes into the Name field. Scope is Workbook. Refers To is this:   `="023456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUWVXYZ"`

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah, but why would you do that? Place the string in `A1`?

Comment: @ExcelHero just going with the comment where the OP stated they put the value in A1 already

Comment: Ahh. I missed that comment. Good call.

Comment: Yeah, if you have the string of 34 characters in cell `A1` you can skip the Name Manager step and just replace all the references to `Pallette` in my formula with `A1`.

Comment: Both options are working! Thanks alot for your help guys! Have a nice day!

Comment: I have a feeling this can be done through PowerQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your allowable character string is in cell `A1` then the following formula will result in random codes that are each five characters in length:

```
=MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1) & MID(A1,RANDBETWEEN(1,34),1)
```

But note that there is no guarantee that the codes will be unique.

As @ScottCraner pointed out... if you should happen to have Office 365, you can use this much shorter formula that takes advantage of two new functions only available in Excel 365:

```
=CONCAT(MID(A1,RANDARRAY(5,,1,34,TRUE),1))
```

But again, there is no guarantee that the resulting codes will be unique.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will generate the codes in order

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(BASE(K, 34,5),"1","Z"),"I","Y")
```

Here `K` can be `0, 1, 2, ...`. One way to generate the first ~1,048,576 K's is to use `ROW()-1`. You could get higher values of K by using something like `K = 1048576*(COLUMN()-1) + ROW()-1`.

The formula works by

(a) calling `BASE(K, 34, 5)` to get a 5-char long base-34 representation of K

(b) substituting `Z` for `1` since `1` is not a valid char

(c) substituting `Y` for `I` since `I` is not a valid char

Comment: And what about character `i`?

Comment: @excel hero I didn't notice that `i` was illegal. I'll fix it.

Comment: Note, this will only generate the first  1,048,576 combinations leaving over 44,000,000 out.

Comment: @ScottCraner I disagree. You can use any value of `K` up to `34^5 - 1`. Using `ROW()-1` is one option and you are correct that for that option you only get the first ~1,048,576 combinations. Also, this solution can be guaranteed to generate unique codes.

Comment: I agree, but then you are back to using a random number generator.  I would make the comment in the answer about the restriction of using row, lest the next user see this and assume the list is complete.

Comment: @ScottCraner Good point. I'll make that clear in the answer.